# How can i use a backgroundworker and a progressbar with ftp file upload?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In form1 designer i have a backgroundworker and i have in the designer set the WorkerReportsProgress and WorkerSupportsCancellation to true.

I have a progressBar1 in form1 designer.

And two backgorundworker events: DoWork and ProgressChanged.
In the DoWork event i'm calling the method that make the ftp file upload from another class:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            uploadftp.upload(@"c:\temp\FtpTestFile.txt", false);
        }
```

In form1 constructor i'm starting the backgroundworker:

```
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
```

And this is the upload method in the uploadftp class:

```
public void upload(string filename, bool uploadtosubortoroot)
    {
        try
        {
            FtpWebRequest request = null;
            if (uploadtosubortoroot == true)
            {
                request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(
                host + "/" + directory + "/" + Path.GetFileName(filename));
            }
            else
            {
                request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(
                host + "/" + Path.GetFileName(filename));
            }
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
            StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(filename);
            byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
            sourceStream.Close();
            request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;
            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

            response.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            string t = err.ToString();
        }    
    }
```

What i wante it to do is when a file is being upload the progressBar will start progress from 0% to 100% where 0% is when it start uploading and 100% when it finish uploading the file.

In the upload method i didn't find any completed event that i can register to so it will tell me that the file was uploaded fine and completed.

EDIT:

This is what i tried so far:

In form1 i added a button in the button click event:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
```

In form1 in the backgorundworker DoWork event i did:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            uploadftp.upload(@"c:\temp\FtpTestFile.txt", false, (BackgroundWorker)sender);
        }
```

In the ProgressChanged event i did:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }
```

And backgorundworker completed event is still empty.

In the class in the upload method i did:

```
public void upload(string filename, bool uploadtosubortoroot,BackgroundWorker bworker)
    {
        try
        {
            FtpWebRequest request = null;
            if (uploadtosubortoroot == true)
            {
                request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(
                host + "/" + directory + "/" + Path.GetFileName(filename));
            }
            else
            {
                request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(
                host + "/" + Path.GetFileName(filename));
            }
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
            StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(filename);
            byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
            sourceStream.Close();
            request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;
            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
            bworker.ReportProgress(0, "Uploading file...");
            requestStream.Close();
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

            response.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            string t = err.ToString();
        }    
    }
```

But it's never report or not progressing.

Comment: I'm not familiar with FtpWebRequest, but here's a suggestion: If your progress bar has, for example, 15 visible steps, then pass that number to the worker thread when you start it. Then replace the statement "requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);" with a small loop that writes 1/15th of the file to requestStream, notifies the GUI thread, writes the next 1/15th of the file, notifies the GUI thread, etc. After you've written the last chunk of the file do the requestStream.Close() and notify the GUI thread that the upload is all done.

Comment: As RenniePet says, if you want to see progress reported, you can't upload the data all in one call. You need to write it in smaller pieces and update the progress between each piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass reference of your `BackgroundWorker` to the `Upload` method
Create eventhandlers for events of `BackgroundWorker`:

`.ReportProgress`  - update progressbar when method `ReportProgress` was executed
[MSDN BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress Method (Int32, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t(v=vs.110).aspx)

`.RunWorkerCompleted` - update progressbar after eventhandler of `DoWork` event was executed

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    uploadftp.upload(@"c:\temp\FtpTestFile.txt", false, (BackgroundWorker)sender);
}

public void upload(string filename, 
                   bool uploadtosubortoroot, 
                   BackgroundWorker bworker)
{
    try
    {
        //I assume your progressbar.MaxValue = 100
        bworker.ReportProgress(0);
        FtpWebRequest request = null;
        if (uploadtosubortoroot == true)
        {
            request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(
            host + "/" + directory + "/" + Path.GetFileName(filename));
        }
        else
        {
            request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(
            host + "/" + Path.GetFileName(filename));
        }
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
        bworker.ReportProgress(20);
        StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(filename);
        byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
        sourceStream.Close();
        request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;
        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
        requestStream.Close();
        bworker.ReportProgress(50);
        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

        response.Close();
        bworker.ReportProgress(100);
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        string t = err.ToString();
    }    
}
```

Comment: Fabio can you look please of what i did so far ? Updated my question. In the upload method in the class i did: bworker.ReportProgress(0, "Uploading file..."); not sure what should i put instead the 0 and not sure if the line i in corrent place and not sure where to put the first line in the upload method that rerport when it's creating.

Comment: And in form1 in the completed event i'm not sure what should i do. I guess i just missed it all up.

Comment: `.RunWorkerCompleted` event handler you can use if you want show something after work was complete in main form(GUI thread). In your case you don't need second parameter for `ReportProgress` method. I updated answer with your code.